# Laravel Socialite - Save URL before redirection

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5.4, laravel-socialite

I'm using `Laravel 5.4` and `Socialite` so my users can log in with `Facebook`.

My website works with subdomain `newyork.example.com`, `paris.example.com` `example.com`

The `Facebook URL` redirect for the callback login has to be `absolute` so I set `http://example.com`

#### login/facebook

```
public function redirectToProvider()
    {

        $_SESSION['originalURL'] ="http://paris.example.com";

        return Socialite::driver('facebook')
            ->scopes(['rsvp_event', 'public_profile'])
            ->redirect();
    }
```

#### login/facebook/callback

```
 public function handleProviderCallback(SocialAccountService $service)
    {
        $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver('facebook')->user());
        // $user->token;

        Auth::login($user, true);

        $originalURL = $_SESSION['originalURL'];

        return redirect()->to($originalURL);
    }
```

#### Problems

When I am in the `route` login/facebook I can view the original URL `paris.example.com` with `HTTP_POST`

When I am in the route `login/facebook/callback` the `HTTP_POST` is `example.com` since the URL of the redirection is `example.com`. I tries to save the URL in a `session var` but `$_SESSION` is empty.

#### Questions

How I can do to get the original url after the facebook login callback redirection. ? So if I started the login process with `paris.example.com` I'm redirected to `example.com` and then I get the save url to be redirected

#### sessions.php

```
'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '.localhost.com'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,
```

Comment: Do you store all your cookies at the example.com level domain ? If so the session could be shared between all subdomains and you can access the data you put in the session from either of them

Comment: You could also put the data inside the `state` you send to Facebook. I'd love to write an answer about that but I'm currently facing another issue with Socialite (found this question while looking for another issue)

Comment: @Kaktus, I copied the `sessions` file. So it might answer your question about cookie storage. Where is the `state` ? Won't it be erased anyway since the callback `url` is fixed beforehand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was not to use `$_SESSION` but  `session(['city' => 'paris'])`;  and `session('city')` to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 6):

I use this way, it's work

```
public function socialConnectRedirect($type, Request $request)
{
    Session::put('redirect', $request->input('redirectTo'));
    if($type=='facebook'){
        return Socialite::driver($type)->scopes(['email', 'public_profile', 'user_birthday', 'user_location'])->redirect();
    }

    return Socialite::driver($type)->redirect();
}
```

In handleSocialCallback function, after user login

```
Auth::login($checkUser);
return redirect(Session::get('redirect'));
Session::forget('redirect');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't share the session between the websites, here's a way to use the `state` OAuth parameter to carry the value along.

This code was tested in a custom OAuth provider. Here's how a Facebook implementation could look like (this specific code is untested).

There are security implications to keep in mind when changing the way the `state` works. Here's an interesting writing on that http://www.thread-safe.com/2014/05/the-correct-use-of-state-parameter-in.html There's even an IETF draft on how one would store and sign data into the `state` parameter https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bradley-oauth-jwt-encoded-state-00 (My implentation below uses JSON and is not signed).

```
<?php

namespace App\Socialite;

use Laravel\Socialite\Two\FacebookProvider;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\User;

class CustomFacebookProvider extends FacebookProvider
{
    protected $statePreviousUrl = null;

    public function withPreviousUrl($url)
    {
        $this->statePreviousUrl = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    protected function getState()
    {
        // The state becomes a JSON object with both the XRSF protection token and the url
        return json_encode([
            'state' => parent::getState(),
            'url' => $this->statePreviousUrl,
        ]);
    }

    protected function hasInvalidState()
    {
        if ($this->isStateless()) {
            return false;
        }

        $storedState = $this->request->session()->pull('state');
        $requestState = $this->request->input('state');
        $requestStateData = json_decode($requestState, true);

        // If the JSON is valid we extract the url here
        if (!is_null($requestStateData) && array_key_exists('url', $requestStateData)) {
            // Don't forget, this value is unsafe. Do additional checks before redirecting to that url
            $this->statePreviousUrl = $requestStateData['url'];
        }

        // If you don't share your session between your instances you can play it "stateless" by always returning false here
        // Doing so you loose all XRSF protection ! (but this might be the only way if you don't share your cookies)
        // return false;

        // If the session is shared, we finish by checking the full state
        // We compare the full json objects, no need to extract the state parameter
        return ! (strlen($storedState) > 0 && $requestState === $storedState);
    }

    protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
    {
        return (new User)->setRaw($user)->map([
            // Data here will vary from provider to provider. The Facebook one is a bit more complex
            'id'    => $user['id'],
            'email' => $user['email'],
            // We add the extracted URL here so it can be access from the controller
            'previous_url' => $this->statePreviousUrl,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Register the custom controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Socialite;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider as BaseServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory;

class ServiceProvider extends BaseServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // @see https://medium.com/laravel-news/adding-auth-providers-to-laravel-socialite-ca0335929e42
        $socialite = $this->app->make(Factory::class);
        $socialite->extend(
            'custom-facebook',
            function ($app) use ($socialite) {
                $config = $app['config']['services.facebook'];
                return $socialite->buildProvider(CustomFacebookProvider::class, $config);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory;

class FacebookLoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var Factory
     */
    protected $socialite;

    public function __construct(Factory $socialite)
    {
        $this->socialite = $socialite;
    }

    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return $this->socialite->driver('custom-facebook')->withPreviousUrl('https://paris.example.com/')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $data = $this->socialite->driver('custom-facebook')->user();

        dd($data->previous_url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used your provider example for another provider (for BattleNet) and it works great. This should be the ideal solution, using state within the design of OAuth itself.