# Laravel socialite, redirect back to page where button was clicked

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-socialite

I have a laravel website where certain news articles are *'gated'*  meaning they have to login/signup in order to read more than the first paragraph.

I have Laravel Socialite installed, so that users can login with Google. What I would like is for users to login via google, then be redirected back to the page which they were viewing before they clicked the 'Login using google' button.

I'll obviously hide the login area when the user is logged in.

Is this possible?

This is my code, however the `redirect()->intended()` does not work:

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    try {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
    
    // check if they're an existing user
    $existingUser = User::where('email', $user->email)->first();
    if($existingUser){
        // log them in
        auth()->login($existingUser, true);
    } else {
        // create a new user
        $newUser                  = new User;
        $newUser->name            = $user->email;
        $newUser->email           = $user->email;
        $newUser->roles_id           = 1;

        $newUser->save();
        auth()->login($newUser, true);
    }
    return redirect()->intended();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

M

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect to URL after login with Socialite in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022774/redirect-to-url-after-login-with-socialite-in-laravel)

Comment: Or, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621555/laravel-socialite-save-url-before-redirection

Comment: Thanks @miken32. The 2nd comment is just what I was looking for! Sessions!

Answer (score 0):

Save the url in a session and retrieve it in the redirect method of the controller.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).